# jQuery equivalent of php's wordwrap?

Tags: php, jquery, word-wrap

I'm looking for a way to use jQuery to do what I can do in php with wordwrap() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

I would use php but I need the wrapping to happen dynamically after the dom is loaded--

I am not familiar enough with jQuery to write this sort of function from scratch and I have run a few google and stack searches trying to find a premade plugin or something that's done it already.

Any ideas? Or perhaps a starting place?

Thanks!

EDIT:
for clarification I need to be able to add html at the line breaks (`</p><p>`, for example)--

as php :

```
wordwrap($text, 8, "</p><p>", true);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/wordwrap-for-javascript/

```
function wordwrap( str, width, brk, cut ) {
     brk = brk || '\n';
     width = width || 75;
     cut = cut || false;

     if (!str) { return str; }

     var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');

     return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );
}
```

Comment: i think this is more or less exactly what im looking for -- do you have any idea how I could use this with jQuery?

Comment: simply, u can use ur native js scripts along jquery, but i u wanna use this inside ur jquery library/module, just put this function as part of ur object (class)

Comment: Man! You're just awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a [word wrap plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/12/jquery-word-wrap-plugin/) for jQuery which is a cross browser solution for word wrapping a `textarea`. If you are not looking to use this on a `textarea` you could try setting the width of the `<p>` tag so that it wraps the text.

Something like

```
<p style="width:50%">some text that is way longer than this</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly with CSS:

```
.break-word {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Word-wrap is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap

Comment: while i'd love to use css to do it -- I need to add html to the DOM -- for example using php I would write wordwrap($str, 8, "<br>"); -- so the css solution isn't going to help, thanks though!