# How to create an automatically word wrap each 40 Characters with JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to create an automatically word wrap every 40 insert characters with java script? I have programmed a jQuery / javascript solution, which used the keyUp event of a textfield:

```
jQuery(textInputfield).keyup(function(event) {      
    var text = jQuery(textInputfield).val();            
    if(text.length == 40){
        text = text + '<br />';
    }    
    var textOutput = jQuery(textOutputField);
    textOutput.empty();
    textOutput.append(text);    
});
```

I need a more flexible solution for this code:

```
if(text.length == 40){
   text = text + '<br />';
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Check here maybe help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423994/jquery-equivalent-of-phps-wordwrap

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution:

```
var text = jQuery(this).val();
text = text.replace(/.{40}/g, '$&<br/>');
```

Comment: Your soultion doesn´t work. I have no word wrap each 40 words, if i use your code snippet

Comment: This will unceremoniously chop words.

Comment: Well, OP said every 40 characters, you could do every 10 words or so.

Comment: True on the technicality :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest against reformatting in this way and instead using a specified width and let the browser make the line break.

Use a specified `width` and `height: auto`

EDIT: see this fiddle for example http://jsfiddle.net/bf9rJ/

Comment: Is it possible to use this in an html "em" tag?: <em id="text" style="width:auto; height:auto;">

Comment: Yes if you put it in a div, see updated answer above